# Dynamic route in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, api, routes, next.js

Before describing my question I would like to show you my file structure.

```
app|
   |->api|
         |->user|
                |->[userId].js
```

[userId].js:

```
export  function GET(req){
   return new Response("Hii")}
```

This is my file structure for the backend. When I put a get request to

> localhost:3000/api/user/12

I'm not getting any response from the server.
It is giving 404 error.
May I know where the problem is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The app folder works slightly different. Route Handlers are now defined in a `route.js` file inside the app directory. So, instead of your folder structure, try this one:

```
app|
   |->api|
         |->user|
                |->[userId]|
                           |route.js
```

Comment: I tried the same this before but it didn't work. Is there anything wrong with the file content.